# Sitecore Multilist with Search datasource outside of sitecore

Tags: json, sitecore, sitecore8.1

My requirement is to have data source for "multilist with search" from third party API which returns JSON. Json do have Ids(Ints) but I want to store them as pipe separated like sitecore store for multilist.

Is there a way to achieve this? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore does not have anything like this OOTB. You need to create a custom multilist field.

Here is a good read to start: http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.be/2012/04/how-to-create-custom-multilist-field.html

Comment: Or a custom black art dataprovider! http://www.techphoria414.com/Blog/2015/September/Black-Art-Revisited-Sitecore-DataProvider-Import-Hybrid

Comment: Haven't seen that one before! Yes, that's another option

Comment: that's for multiList, is there any example of multiList with search?